# Trying to call javascript from C# with ASPX project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, response.redirect, registerstartupscript

I have this in my aspx page right after the form id="form1" runat="server" tag: (had to strip the > and <)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openLocationForm(locationId)
        {
            window.open('FlagLocationViewForm.aspx?id=' + locationId), '_blank');
        }
    </script>
```

The FlagLocationViewForm.aspx page does exist and expects a parameter passed to it. If I just cause the page to load with a Response.Redirect("FlagLocationViewForm.aspx"); it loads, but not in a new tab.

And I have this in the .cs file that is associated with this .aspx page that has the script mentioned above.

```
protected void GridViewCustomerList_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewSelectEventArgs args = (GridViewSelectEventArgs)e;

    GridViewRow row = GridViewCustomerList.Rows[args.NewSelectedIndex];
    
    int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Text);

    string scriptToRun = "openLocationForm('" + customerId.ToString() + "');";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), scriptToRun, true);

}
```

The page is causing GridViewCustomerList_SelectedIndexChanging to fire - that all works. But the RegisterStartupScript does not do anything. If I substitute the following for the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript line:

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Hello');", true);

I get the alert that says 'Hello' displayed.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing if you inspect the Dev Tools console of your browser, you will find a message about `openLocationForm` being undefined.

I think what may be happening here is that the `openLocationForm` function does not exist yet. If you inspect the source code, you will most likely see the startup script appear *before* the function definition.

Move your function definition higher (e.g. to the head section) and it should work.

Comment: I decided to make it a modal popup instead.